# Linux starts using 4G dongle when plugged even though wifi dongle is set to default

Tags: networking, iptables, network-interface

I have a remote raspberry pi running wth an wifi dongle. I can only access it through SSH. Whenever I ask my father to connect the 4G dongle, I cannot access the pi anymore. If removed, things start working again. Seems like everything is getting routed to the 4G dongle after its plugged.

This is the output before the dongle is plugged:

```
ip route list
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  metric 303 
169.254.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.41.13  metric 204 
169.254.0.0/16 dev veth1005631  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.175.70  metric 206 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.161  metric 303
```

things should go to `wlan0` as default. Anybody has any idea of what is happening?

I think the dongle is configured to use `192.168.1.1`. Could it be a problem?

Do you have any idea to mitigate this problem remotely?

**UPDATE:**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:a2:09:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::ce99:232c:964e:7070/64 scope link tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:dd:90:5d:5f:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.161/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7bf8:a0f7:2dc9:b042/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c0:47:05:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.41.13/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6e2e:e1a5:dec1:cb44/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: veth1005631@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether 22:9e:88:7e:ef:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.175.70/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global veth1005631
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::145d:c10d:cd27:5880/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: What does `ip addr` say? It sounds like you have an address conflict, but this would indicate for sure whether that's the case.

Comment: @ErikF updated with ip addr